# IP allow subdirectory access NGINX

Tags: nginx

im actually using nginx as my webserver im trying to deny all a subdirectory access  using this:

```
location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html/project;
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;
}



location ~ ^/subdir/ { 
    allow 192.168.1.0/24; 
    deny all; 
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index_subdir.php?$query_string;
}
```

but nginx try to find out index_subdir.php inside project folder.

I hope you can give me a hand.

Kind regards!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to make several changes:

```
server {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html/project;
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;

    location / {
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        ...
    }

    location ^~ /subdir { 
        allow 192.168.1.0/24; 
        deny all; 

        try_files $uri $uri/ /subdir/index_subdir.php?$query_string;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Generally, `root` and `index` directives are placed at the `server` block level so that all `location` blocks inherit the same value. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for details.

I assume that you have a `location ~ \.php$` block that currently executes all of your PHP scripts.

My example uses a prefix location with the `^~` modifier, rather than a regular expression location. The modifier makes it take precedence irrespective of position within the `server` block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

The final element of the `try_files` directive is a URI, which means it must include the `/subdir` prefix, if you specifically want the file within that folder. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

You need to replicate another `location ~ \.php$` within the `location ^~ /subdir` block so that the PHP scripts are protected by the same access rules.

Comment: Hello Richard Smith, i already apply changes as you suggested and its works!!!.
Thank you very much for your help.
Kind regards!!!