# nginx block POST /adm/ for all except one ip

Tags: regex, nginx, location

Hackers ddos server with POST /adm/ requests, there are mix of php and static content in /adm.
how to block this particular location for all except whitelisted ip?

I tried:

```
^~ /adm/
^~ /adm/$
^~ "/adm/ $"
```

doesn't work, `curl -I -X POST https://example.com/adm/` returns 200.

`^~ /adm` doesn't suite because I need to separate php-fpm and static content,
`^~ /adm/\.+\.php` partialy works, but I need also `^~ /adm/(NOT PHP)` for css, etc.

`~* /adm` doesn't work at all I guess because other locations exists

any ideas please?

Comment: Only `^~ /adm/` is valid syntax. But if this location contains PHP files, you will need to use a nested location. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40428709/ip-allow-subdirectory-access-nginx/40432650#40432650)

Comment: hmm, nested location, never saw it before, thanks for idea.